# How to setup stream recording on a cloud platform like GCP?

Tags: streaming, vnc, google-cloud-platform

Here's the scenario I'm trying to figure out:

- There's a website that streams live content e.g. `twitch`.
- I have a virtual machine set up on a cloud platform like `GCP`.
- I'm able to record these streams locally by means of software like `OBS`.
- I want to achieve the same thing on the VM I have in the cloud.

The problems that I need help with:

Do I need to setup a GUI and connect to the VM via VNC and then start recording content as usual and close the VNC session? VNC setup would be as described over [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/graphical-user-interface-gui-for-google-compute-engine-instance-78fccda09e5c).

Or is there a way in which I can setup recording via CLI and then download the recorded content later?

I can elaborate further if anyone needs more clarification.

Comment: Don’t “record” it, just download the video stream.

Comment: those are live streams, so I'm not sure what you mean by just download them. can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Live, not live, doesn't matter. Its just a bunch of little two second videos that are played back seamlessly. Its called HLS (in twitch's case) Just look that up. There are a million tools to download it.